# How do I access mouse pointer location when dragging using dndkit?

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, dnd-kit

That's the whole question. I want to implement something like this. For that, I have to know when the mouse is in the top or bottom green or when it's the middle yellow.

[image]